# Golang Regexp Reference within MustCompile (Find repeating character)

Tags: regex, go

I am having a hard time with Go's regex. It seems it's different than other language, can someone help me on this.

Obj. I want MustCompile to find all repeated characters in the string.
APPLE (where P's repeating)

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(\\w)\\${1}\\+")
```

Above is what I have tried but didn't work at all. Basically I wanted to do:

```
([A-Za-z])\1+
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Example below:

https://play.golang.org/p/DeuaIva968

Comment: At first look I think `+` should not be escaped if that's what you are doing with `\\\`, because then it will be literal and not meta-character.

Comment: That was one of the attempt :) I tried every combination, and still couldn't find why it's not working.. :'(

Comment: Did you tried `(\w)\1+` ?

Comment: Yes, not working; Go's regexp is really different

Comment: [MustCompile is like Compile but panics if the expression cannot be parsed. It simplifies safe initialization of global variables holding compiled regular expressions.](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile)

Comment: Try with `(\\w)\\1\+`. If this doesn't work then I will have to go through whole documentation.

Comment: Sorry noob; it's not working. Go's regexp is very different than Python or Java somehow.. See https://play.golang.org/p/4kDJMbT1jH you can try there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108737/discussion-between-noob-and-gon).

Comment: It seems `regexp` package of `go` do not support `backreferences`

Comment: Sadly it seems so.. Closing question. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Golang doesn't supposed back referencing due to efficiency. :(
Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Is this still true in 2022?